# How do I properly combine 2 foreach loops into one another in part of sql query?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have Information in the database that shares the same FK but unique PK, and so I looping it to display on the page. And I wanted to build an SQL Update Query to be able to update it. I have now 2 loops but I'm not sure how to fully combine them so that it works in one.

What am I missing or what do I need to do in order to be able to get the results I need so that when I run the code it updates the unique field that should be updated? Should I rather put a for-each loop inside of another for-each loop would that work?

This is the code to connect and get the information from the database and then a loop to display the values and the id fields.

```
//connect
$sql_awards = "select `awards`, `awardsid` from inf_awards where inf_id = $vId";
$rs_awards = mysqli_query($vconncvnl, $sql_awards);

//display inputs
while ($rs_awards_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_awards)) {
echo '<input type="text" name="awardact[]" id="awardact" class="awardactadd" value="' . $rs_awards_rows['awards'] . '">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="txtaward[]" value="'. $rs_awards_rows['awardsid'] .'">';
}
```

So now I can get the information to a process page I also have an SQL update statement and a looped

the foreach loop i used to display the awards id and then the foreach loop for the sql Code

```
//construction of loop for the awardsID field
$awardsId = '';
$award = $_POST['txtaward'];

foreach ($award as $awardid){
         $awardsId .= $awardid;
}

//construction of the loop for building the SQL Update Query
$sql_up_award = '';
foreach ($vaccolates as $valuesawards) {
                $sql_up_award .= sprintf("UPDATE inf_awards SET awards = %s WHERE inf_id = $vid AND awardsid = $awardsId ; ". "<br>", escapestring($vconncvnl, $valuesawards,'text'));
            }
```

but when I do it like this it gives me

```
UPDATE inf_awards SET awards = 'john smith honorary' WHERE inf_id = 2 AND awardsid = 23; 
UPDATE inf_awards SET awards = 'Best scorer' WHERE inf_id = 2 AND awardsid = 23;
```

im guessing this is cause of the previous loop now that when i call it in it will just loop every value that meets the requirement which at this point is just '23' however

The Results I would want to be is like

```
UPDATE inf_awards SET awards = 'john smith honorary' WHERE inf_id = 2 AND awardsid = 2; 
UPDATE inf_awards SET awards = 'Best scorer' WHERE inf_id = 2 AND awardid = 3;
```

Comment: You can do it 2 ways:
1) generate queries in first loop, not second (why are you contacternating IDs as string anyway?)
2) use single query with IN():
$idList = implode(',', $award); 
$query = "UPDATE inf_awards SET awards = %s WHERE inf_id = $vid AND awardsid IN ({$idList});"

Comment: @KonradGałęzowski so when i try way 1) then my issue becomes the `awards = 'na '` since the loop is now doing the numbers (and if i nest it then it gives me 4 answers not 2) and im not quite sure what the second one is? i dont think ive ever used IN() ill look into that but if theres anything else you can help with id be glad to hear it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested loops are not going to solve it, because you'll end up with 4 updates.

You have two arrays, one with the ids, one with the values. You can make a single for loop and get the matching values by index.

However, I think this is not completely safe, since I'm afraid that people could make the texts empty and that way screw up your array, so it's important to at least check beforehand that both arrays contain the same number of items:

```
if (count($award) != count($valuesawards)) {

  echo 'Please fill in all the names';

} else {

    $sql_up_award = '';

    //construction of the loop for building the SQL Update Query
    $sql_up_award = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($award); $i++) (
      $awardid = $award[$i];
      $valuesawards = $vaccolates[$i];
      $sql_up_award .= sprintf("UPDATE inf_awards SET awards = %s WHERE inf_id = $vid AND awardsid = $awardsId ; ". "<br>", escapestring($vconncvnl, $valuesawards,'text'));
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @GolezTrol, thanks for answer however I am having a slight issue with the line that goes `$vaccolates as $valuesawards[$i];` it is showing up as an error in my text editor it says 'expression results unused'

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `=` instead of `as`. I can't promise there aren't other small typo's in there, because I typed it in Notepad from the top of my head based you your question code. ;-)

Comment: yea i figured that it was meant to be an `=` instead of `as` and i also switched them around so its ` $valueasawards = $vaccolates[$i];` otherwise i get a message saying "undefined variable" but otherwise yea the code works thanks man :D